# UIBarButtonItem -> unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a UIBarButtonItem and i want to pushViewController in an other class. So i have this line of code in viewDidLoad :

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"settings"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GoToPages.goToSettings(_:)))
```

This is my GoToPages class :

```
import UIKit

class GoToPages: UIViewController {

   @objc func goToSettings(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem) {

        let button = sender

        switch button.tag {
        case 0:
            let settingsPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Notifications")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsPageView!, animated: true)
        case 1:
            let settingsPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings")
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsPageView!, animated: true)
        default:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

But i get an error :  unrecognized selector sent to instance.

Comment: What class is that first line of code in? In other words, what exactly is `self` when creating the button item?

Answer (score 1):

The value of the parameter `target` must be the *instance* of the class the `action` is implemented in.

`self` implies that the `action` is implemented in the current class.

Comment: So what will be the correct code? I tried target: GoToPages.self but it is not working...

Comment: I wrote : *... must be the **instance** of the class*. You need the reference to the actual instance of `GoToPages`.

Comment: Now i tried :         self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named:"settings"), style: .plain, target: GoToPages(), action: #selector(GoToPages.goToSettings(_:)))

No error now but noting append when i click on the Bar button item...

Comment: No. `GoToPages()` creates a new instance which is not the instance in the view hierarchy. Once again, *you need the reference to the actual instance* which is instance in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Ok but how i can do that, i just want a class that i can use in each ViewController to push the views according to UIBarButtonItem tag ID pressed? I don't want to have to reuse all the code because i want it shorter.

Comment: Is an extension of `UIViewController` an option?

Comment: Can i create the extension in the class? I never play with extension...

Comment: Just define an extension of `UIViewController` and implement the method. Then **any** instance of `UIViewController` will respond to the method.

Comment: Ok i will try that and be back with the feedback, thanks

Comment: By the way, the question is not particularly related to Swift 4

Answer (score 1):

You should delete 'GoToPages.' from selector definition of `#selector(GoToPages.goToSettings(_:))`:

```
#selector(goToSettings(_:))
```

Because GoToPages.goToSettings is class function and should be instance method to work due to your argument 'target: self'. Here self specifies instance and therefore your selector must be instance method.

Just in case this doesn't solve your problem, use `self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(...)` instead of assigning directly to `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = ...`

Here is the code which works for me:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image"),
                                        style: .plain,
                                        target: self,
                                        action: #selector(barButtonItemTapped(sender:))
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([barButtonItem], animated: true)
}

@objc private func barButtonItemTapped(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My code :

import UIKit

extension UIViewController {

```
@objc func goToPage(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let button = sender as? UIBarButtonItem else {
        return
    }

    switch button.tag {
    case 0:
        let settingsPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Notifications")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsPageView!, animated: true)
    case 1:
        let settingsPageView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Settings")
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(settingsPageView!, animated: true)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```